# Unable to load the data from other controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller, which is composed of many other partial views. I wanted to use a particular section of that controller in another controller. I am able to see the design but unable to load items in it.

Let say I have one controller named "Products" within Product view folder I have `_items.cshtml`. I wanted to use this `_items.cshtml` in another controller called "placeTheOrder".

In particular section of **div** in placeTheOrder view I referred to `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Products/_items.cshtml")`. Even after doing so it is unable to load the content from `_items.cshtml` into placeTheOrder.

What am I doing wrong.

`_items.cshtm`l view

```
    <div id="accordionProduct" class="span-6 last prod-acc">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/product/_ezCpSearchBar.cshtml")
        <div id="filterPanel" class="span-6 last filter-panel">
            <div class="span-6 last">
                <div class="filter-panel-head">
                    <h1>Filter</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span-6 last">
                <div class="filter-panel-body">
                    &nbsp;
                    <div class="filter-panel-prop"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionProductInner" class="span-6 last prod-acc-body">
        </div>
    </div>
    // this is the script are where the content gets loaded into the view
    <div id="TemplateFilterItem" class="hidden"></div>
    <div id="TemplateLastViewItem" class="hidden"></div>
```

This is the place where I have refered to it in another controller

```
<div class="span-6" style="background-color:#d4d4d4;padding:20px;">     
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/product/_items.cshtml")
</div>
```

Comment: So do you want to load just the partial view as html without going through a controller action?

Comment: can you add your code to the question ?

Comment: Yeah exactly @AmrElgarhy. I am able to see the html on the page but I also need to load the content in it.

Comment: Which html you can see and which you want to load? it is not clear for me, adding some code will be quite helpful

Comment: I added the code @AmrElgarh,

Comment: Using `@Html.Partial()` just renders the html in the partial and you have not passed a model to it so no items will be shown. If your want to call a server method that populates a model and returns a view of it then you need `Html.Action(actionName, controllerName)`. But you have not shown any of the relevant controller code so no one can answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Html.Renderpartial in your view instead

Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/ControllerName/ViewName.cshtml", ModelData);

If you are using different  model for both the views then you need to make ViewModel which will include required properties.

Hope this Helps